# Total pattern match in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, search

I am using Postgres to match a pattern in a column of strings, without the full text search engine (because I don't want stemming, stopwords, ranking, etc.).

How can I retrieve the total number of patterns that match (even if more one field contains the pattern multiple times). Is that possible?

For instance: searching for dog in

```
text
----

The dog looked at the other dog.
The dog looked at the cat.
```

Result when searching for dog: 3 hits.

Answer (score 1):

`regexp_matches` returns one row for each match if called with the `g` parameter. You can use this to count the number of matches found if you have a primary key column in the table.

```
select id, count(*)
from the_table, regexp_matches(the_column, 'dog', 'g')
where the_column ~ 'dog'
group by id
```

The condition `where the_column ~ 'dog'` reduces the number of rows that need to be processed and thus the number of rows that need to be group. If you only have a few rows that contain the search term this should improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
SUM(
  (LENGTH(text) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(text,'dog','','g'))) / LENGTH('dog')
) as hits
FROM
the_table
```

**Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/600f5/1

Comment: Nice, I have seen this snippet around on the web before, now I remember. Is this fast enough on a table with 1m rows? And does this mean I run two queries: one to count and one to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with full text search without using stemming and stopwords. You can use "simple" dictionary. More about dictionaries in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html).

Here the example for the table "tst":

```
CREATE TABLE tst (t text);
INSERT INTO tst VALUES ('The dog looked at the other dog.');
INSERT INTO tst VALUES ('The dog looked at the cat.');
```

Example query which uses the function ts_stat():

```
postgres=# SELECT SUM(nentry) FROM ts_stat('SELECT to_tsvector(t) FROM tst') WHERE word = 'dog';
 sum 
-----
   3
(1 row)
```

I do not know about performance of ts_stat(). You can test it with indexes.